# Do I have to resize and manually move the checkbox with a Unity Toggle?

Tags: unity

I have a Toggle UI element (the stock one from Unity 5.2), and when I resize it to make the text legible, the checkbox doesn't resize or move:

[image]

Am I missing something, or is the control implementation incomplete?

Comment: I've deleted my previous answer

Comment: Sorry I left out the specifics of which Toggle I was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the anchors of the Background and Checkmark GameObjects so they get resized when you resize the Toogle gameobject.

You can do it using the RectTransform component:
 [image]

Click first in the upper left icon, then in the lower right one

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.2 UI stuff. Will edit the question.

Comment: This partially solves the problem, combined with picking the right horizontal size for the check to scale to proper aspect ratio, plus moving it so it doesn't overlap the text.

Comment: Probably you can anchor the label to the check so it moves if the check changes size but it is sure overkill: game UI does not usually use such intricate dynamic layouts